# adding datetime on video while video recording in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am new in iPhone sdk. I want to develop a project in which i need to record current date and time along while i am recording video. i am not getting how to do that. please help me out here.
please provide a sample if possible.

Thank You

Comment: are you trying to make watermark in video currently recording? or you need a way how to store date-time along to video? or to get timestamp from video metadata?

Comment: I need a way how to store date-time along to video. currently i am able to show current running date time on video recorder as overlay. i need that to be record along the recorded video too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDate date`will return a NSDate object with the current date and
time. Sample code to find the current date and time is as follows

```
NSDate *testDate=[NSDate date]; 
NSDateFormatter *formatterNew = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [formatterNew setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"]; 
NSString *dt = [formatterNewstringFromDate:testDate]; 
NSString *strDateTaken=dt; 
NSLog(@"date=%@",strDateTaken); 
[formatterNew release];
```

> and you can easily save this date in NSUserDefault for later retrival

Comment: hi Talktobijju, your code is correct, but I need this date should be record along with video recording in iPhone. how to add this current running date in video while i am taking video.